# Django else statement in html template not working

Tags: django

Why my else statement not working in html template. It should be display text **"You don't have any notification"** if user didn't have any notification. I am using else statement in my html template for showing the text but why text isn't showing? here is my code:

```
{% for notification in  notifications  %} 
{%if user.id ==  notification.blog.author.id %}
{% if notification.notification_type == "Comment Approved" %}
     Your Blog Post {{notification.blog.title}} received new commnet
{%else%}
    <h1>Don't have any notification</h1>
{% endif %} 

{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
```

when user don't have any notification I am getting empty html page. If user have notification then it's displaying but I am not understanding why my else statement not working when user don't have any notifications.

Comment: Look carefully, which `if` statement does that `else` belong to? Plus that logic does not seem to make sense still, and why are you filtering stuff in the template that way? Do it in the _view_ and pass it into the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your else is matching with the `{% if notification.notification_type == "Comment Approved" %}`, this means that it will render for each notification that is for which the blog author is the current user, and the notification type is comment approved.

I would advise that you filter in the *view* (not the template, Django templates should *not* implement *business logic*, only *rendering* logic). This is not only more elegant, but likely more efficient, since you can do the filtering at the database side and work with:

```
<!--                   ↓           ↓ filter in the view -->
{% for notification in notifications %} 
     Your Blog Post {{notification.blog.title}} received new commnet
{% empty %}
    <h1>Don't have any notification</h1>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your details explanation